# Google calendar API update "Missing end time"

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I'm trying to update an event using:

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/q4es0o2o70naq8idj1dj6q4354

{
 "reminders" {"useDefault":true},
 "summary":"updatedsummary",
 "description":"updated desc"
}
```

but get a response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Missing end time."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Missing end time."
 }
}
```

Why do I need a end time if I just need to update a summary or other fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId
```

is [events.update](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) update requires that all of the fields be filled in.  The best way to use it would be to do an [event.get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) change the fields you want then post that back.

**Better option**

Use [events.patch](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) instead if you just want to update a few fields.

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId
```

Comment: This particular answer has been very useful in my use case and should be more documented in the Google Calendar API, especially as myself and no doubt many other users may initially refer to the 'Update' method to update specific variables. As in this case, the 'Patch' method is far more effective and perhaps should've been referred to as 'Update' as that make more sense.

Comment: Very good point I will see if I can find someone at Google to report it to.

Comment: Thank you @DalmTo - I have just posted a feedback message on the particular page of the API. Your answer has just saved me considerable time trying to find out why I couldn't just update a few specific fields without entering additional info. I have been in rush getting the particular functionality setup and never looked, knew of or even guessed to consider 'Patch' as a suitable alternative! Thanks again